# Jasperserver report not shown JSON data adapter

Tags: jasperserver, jaspersoft-studio

I am using Jaspersoft to create reports for my web application. I've been able to make reports work using SQL datasources (hence,connecting it to postgres, running queries and populating the report) but now it is giving me a really hard time with JSON.

These are the steps I am taking:

1. I create a file JSON data adapter which has the url of my web service with the authorization header and the id which I pass a parameter. (It works perfectly in jaspersoft)
2. I  save the adapter as a file, pic below shows how

   [image]
3. I import such file in my Server like this:

   [image]
4. I finally deploy my report on server and, whereas it works perfectly when I run the preview, when it comes to the server itself it says that the report is empty.

I really have no idea why this happens. As I said before, if I communicate directly with the database I have none of this problems and it all works fine but we'd prefer to use our web services to populate the data.